# issue with the div width

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am using kind of following layout.
[image]

All the elements are div with a background image and another image for the text.
The layout is having issue on Kindle Fire HD ( 800 X 1280 px). The bottom two buttons are shorten from left hand side, although all the parameters used for the below two divs are same as that of the above two divs.

I want the width of all the divs to be same. Any help please..

Relevant HTML Code for the divs

```
   <div id="div1" ></div>
    <div id="div1Text"  ></div>

    <div id="div2"> </div>
    <div id="div2Text"> </div>

    <div id="pieChart" style="background-color:nil;"><canvas id="can" style="background-color:nil; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;"></canvas></div>

    <div id="div3" > </div>
    <div id="div3Text" > </div>

    <div id="div4" ></div>
    <div id="div4Text"></div>
```

Css block for Kindle Fire HD

```
@media only screen and  (device-width : 800px) and (device-height : 1280px) and (orientation :
portrait) {
#div1 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/common/BTN.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 428px;
    height: 74px;
    background-size: 428px 74px;
    margin-top: 240px;
    margin-left: 186px;
}
#div1Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text1.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 336px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 336px 28px;
    margin-top: 255px;
    margin-left: 232px;
}
#div2 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/common/BTN.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 428px;
    height: 74px;
    background-size: 428px 74px;
    margin-top: 350px;
    margin-left: 186px;
}
#div2Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text2.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 231px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 231px 28px;
    margin-top: 365px;
    margin-left: 284px;
}
#pieChart {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Progress-Wheel.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 288px;
    height: 288px;
    background-size: 288px 288px;
    margin-top: 460px;
    margin-left: 256px;
}
#div3 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad/victor/BTN.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 428px;
    height: 74px;
    background-size: 428px 74px;
    margin-top: 800px;
    margin-left: 186px;
}

#div3Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text3.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 176px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 176px 28px;
    margin-top: 815px;
    margin-left: 312px;
}


#div4 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad/victor/BTN.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 428px;
    height: 74px;
    background-size: 428px 74px;
    margin-top: 910px;
    margin-left: 186px;
}

#div4Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text4.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 211px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 211px 28px;
    margin-top: 925px;
    margin-left: 294px;
}
}
```

Comment: Please upload the code of your .xml file.

Comment: I am using phonegap and hence CSS for the layout.

Comment: oh sorry, I am not aware about Phonegap. I do native Android code only.

Comment: Please include code to narrow the scope of the issue. The html and relevant css will allow others to review and find a solution.

Comment: Updated the ques with the relevant part of the code. Please check

Comment: I don't see anything that looks incorrect. As a debug check, try removing the canvas element and see if div3 and div4 look correct then. If so, then there is an issue with the display of the canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` should be used a few times. You should rather use `position:relative`. It would allow you to save time from calculating the distance from the top and the left.

If you want your div to be centered, you should use this :

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Moreover, if your `#divXText` are supposed to be inside your `#divX`, you should explicitly declare it in your html :

```
<div id="divX" >
    <div id="divXText"></div>
</div>
```

Here is what I suggest :

HTML :

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div1Text"></div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <div id="div2Text"></div>
</div>

<div id="pieChart" style="background-color:nil;"><canvas id="can" style="background-color:nil; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;"></canvas></div>

<div id="div3">
    <div id="div3Text"></div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
    <div id="div4Text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#div1, #div1Text, #div2, #div2Text, #div3, #div3Text, #div4, #div4Text, #pieChart {
    /* Centering */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    width: 428px;
    height: 59px;
    background-size: 428px 74px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#div2, #div3, #div4, #pieChart {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#div1 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/common/BTN.png);
    margin-top: 240px;
}

#div1Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text1.png);
    width: 336px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 336px 28px;
}

#div2 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/common/BTN.png);
}

#div2Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text2.png);
    width: 231px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 231px 28px;
}

#pieChart {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Progress-Wheel.png);
    width: 288px;
    height: 288px;
    background-size: 288px 288px;
}

#div3 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad/victor/BTN.png);
}

#div3Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text3.png);
    width: 176px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 176px 28px;
}

#div4 {
    background-image:
        url(../ScreenImages/iPad/victor/BTN.png);
}

#div4Text {
    background-image: url(../ScreenImages/iPad@2x/home/Text4.png);
    width: 211px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 211px 28px;
}
```

NB : The height of the `#divX` is 59 instead of 74, because the `padding-top` attribute is added to the height (59+15=74).

NB2 : I'm not sure the `background-size` attribute is really useful.